# Seleccionar letras de un String sin importar caracteres C#

Tags: c#, string, split, caracteres

Tengo una duda y no sé cómo buscar solución a dicha duda porque no sé cómo preguntarle a San Google. Mi duda es la siguiente:

Supongamos que tengo unas cadenas:

`TRD_12_ASDF_5_ASDADAAS.txt`
`TRD_12_ASDF_5_GHYRUIHA.txt`
`TRD_11_ASDF_8_AGADAAS.txt`

En las cadenas anteriores hay ciertos patrones.
¿Hay un operador que permita seleccionar cierta posición de cierta cadena?

Algo como:
`TRD_12_ASDF_5_*.txt`
ó
`TRD_12_ASDF_5_*.*`

Aclaro que mi duda es sobre los caracteres, no sobre las posiciones (para la segunda sé que puedo usar un Split).

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo así como [expresiones regulares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te puede servir la extensión para cadena `StartsWith`.

A continuación, pseudo código, la respuesta la puedes implementar.

Supongamos que tu array es cadenas

```
public string ObtenerCandena(string s)
{
    foreach(var cadena in cadesnas)
    {
        //si una subcadena esta contenida se devuelve true
        if(candena.StartsWith(s))
        return cadena;
    }
    return string.empty
}

//ejemplo tienes 
List<string> cadenas=new {"TRD_12_ASDF_5_ASDADAAS.txt",
"TRD_12_ASDF_5_GHYRUIHA.txt",
"TRD_11_ASDF_8_AGADAAS.txt"};

//buscando "ASDF_8"
var cadenaEncontrada=ObtenerCadena("ASDF_8");

//cadenaEncontrada="TRD_11_ASDF_8_AGADAAS.txt";
```

Saludos.

Comment: Pero eso implicaría que todas las cadenas  tienen que empezar con la misma letra, no hay un equivalente al  asterisco que funciona en las expresiones regulares? sin que sea necesario usar alguna libreria?

Comment: @Brayan creo que Miguel tiene idea de lo que requieras, pero para que quede un poco más claro, pondría el parámetro `s` que sea igual a `TRD_12_ASDF_5_`, entonces al decir  `"TRD_12_ASDF_5_ASDADAAS.txt".StartsWith(s)` regresaría un `true` porque la cadena efectivamente empieza con ese texto

Comment: Gracias, realmente me sacaron de dudas... recién empiezo en el mundo de la programación... por ello no se como preguntar por algunas cosas...
Mil Disculpas y Gracias :D